# SQL Server 2008R2 - data in perm table but not in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not sure why this is happening... the actual table has data yet when trying to pull data from the actual table into the temp table, there is no data...

```
IF object_id('DI_Temp.di.Holly') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE DI_Temp.di.Holly

CREATE TABLE DI_Temp.di.Holly
(
Toys varchar(20)
,Meals varchar(100)
,Breaks varchar(20)
)

Insert DI_Temp.DI.Holly 
   Select 
      Toys, Meals, Breaks
   from toysarefun.dbo.crazytoys (nolock)
   where status = 'active'

--Select * from di_temp.di.holly

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Toys') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#Toys

SELECT * 
INTO #Toys
FROM DI_Temp.di.Holly (NOLOCK) 
WHERE Toys like 'H*'

Select *
from tempdb.dbo.#Toys
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you are not comparing apples with apples. Your test select should include the SAME filter as the INSERT..SELECT query

Secondly, it's best to minimize the time spent on `SELECT.. INTO`. Better to create the temporary table first.

Thirdly, don't use `tempdb.dbo.#Toys`. # is implicitly in tempdb.  You will get this warning anyway

> Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.

The changed portions:

```
-- uncomment first to check if there are any matches
--Select * from di_temp.di.holly WHERE Toys like 'H*'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Toys') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Toys;

SELECT *
INTO #Toys
FROM DI_Temp.di.Holly (NOLOCK) 
WHERE 1=0;

INSERT INTO #Toys
SELECT * 
FROM DI_Temp.di.Holly (NOLOCK) 
WHERE Toys like 'H*';
```

Comment: Thank you Richard! Since I am learning SQL coding - can you kindly explain to me what WHERE 1=0; means. It's working. Just needing to know what that meant. :)

Comment: The WHERE clause is a condition (filter) for the query. `WHERE 1=0` is a condition that can never be true, just as `WHERE 'a'='b'` is false. Since the condition is never true, no rows will be inserted into #toys on creation. Yet the statement itself achieves the creation of the table.